# Android GCM account necessary for each device?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

Im working on an app with server-client communication. It will have a small 
messaging system and maybe i will also synchronize the conigurations with GCM.
All users have to register to use the app and to use the functionalities 
from our provided website and they can communicate with other registered user
using the app or the website.

If i use GCM to implement the messaging and the config synchronization, **does 
every user has to have a google account?** This [Tutorial](http://androidexample.com/Android_Push_Notifications_using_Google_Cloud_Messaging_GCM/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=119&aaid=139) says that i have
to create a google account. That wouldnt be good for me.. actually i dont want
my users to be forced to have a google account.

Comment: No there is no need, its just to keep the record in database!

Comment: Keep the record in database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Android GCM Overview](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gcm.html)

> It uses an existing connection for Google services. For pre-3.0 devices, this requires users to set up their Google account on their mobile devices. A Google account is not a requirement on devices running Android 4.0.4 or higher.

Comment: Sunit2k15 wrote, that every user needs a google account. whats true now?

Comment: I did. As always it leads to more questions than it answers.

Comment: So the answer is: Users with Android<3.0 will need a Google Account. Other users don't. That means that about 83% of users won't need a Google Account.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using GCM from the google play service library yes you need a google account because google play services gets updated through the play store.